# Reading a file and replacing the current line

Tags: c++, file-io, replace

I am trying to read a file using ifstream. And while reading (line-by-line), it encrypts each line and has to replace the original line with the new encrypted line. I have so far been able to read from the file but replacing the current line ( current line = line last read ) is what I can't figure out how to do. My question it: How do I replace a line in a file which I last read, using getline(...)?

Comment: You're probably going to have to write to a new file.

Comment: Seriously? No other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can't delete a specific data in a file; you have to write it from the beginning.
But with f_seek and r+ you may insert some data whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I choose to write from beginning.